# How to fetch the Leaf Node value from lyd_node* received from server in Netopeer2 Client?

Tags: ietf-netconf, netconf, libyang

I'm using Netopeer2 library for Netconf client and server. Command line program source codes of client and server are available.
In client side, upon executing get-config for specific yang model, the response is printed in the command line.
However I want to fetch the value of the **Leaf node** from that response and use it for my application.
The response is received in *lyd_node**.

I got the hint online to use lyd_find_path() of libyang to do this. I called it like this:
*LY_ERR ret = lyd_find_path(op, "/etsi-qkd-sdn-node:qkd_node/qkdn_version", 1, &match);*

Upon debugging lyd_find_path(), I found that it is failing at the line
*ret = ly_path_eval_partial(lypath, ctx_node, NULL, 0, NULL, match).*
The error value is: **LY_ENOTFOUND**